# Could not find method kotlin() for arguments [gradle-plugin, 1.3.20]

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I've copied exactly what the [kotlin gradle docs say](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#plugin-and-versions) to implement kotlin gradle plugin, however it's returning the following error:

`Could not find method kotlin() for arguments [gradle-plugin, 1.3.20] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

**my gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.3.20"))

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
//    ext {
//        navigationVersion = '28.0.0'
//    }
    plugins {
        kotlin("<...>")
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

`build.gradle` can be written in Groovy or Kotlin. You're typing your `build.gradle` in Groovy (not Kotlin), but you have copied the Kotlin code. You should select the Groovy tab on the documentation:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"
    }

}
```

Here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-android

You can also find a decent example by creating an empty Android and Kotlin project.

Comment: For anyone ending up here from 2023 on, this caused my build to fail where it previously succeeded.